# Day and Night mode according to user's real local time

Tags: unity

How do I make it so the texture of my plane is a black sky when it's night according to player's local time (say from 10 PM to 5 AM it's going to be black, and from 6 AM to 9 AM it's going to be a blue sky)?

Blue sky texture name is "bluesky"
Black sky texture name is "blacksky"

Thanks.

Comment: I'll get you halfway there: `System.DateTime.Now.Hour`

Comment: I'd definitely think twice about doing something like that to the player: You're essentially forcing people to experience the game based on their local time. So if they're only able to play at night, they'll never see the daylight in your game. In a similar fashion, they might feel forced to modify their local PC clock just to experience everything. Either way, I'd consider this bad design rather than immersive gameplay or anything similar. Only do it, if you've got a very, very good reason to do it.

Comment: I agree with Mario (I played a game like this once, always at night, and I eventually got stuck because I didn't play during daytime). If you do this, compress time so that a couple of minutes of real time increment game time by an hour. (See Terraria for a reference)

Comment: But what if I want to create a Sims clone with Multiplayer? Should I use server time instead of local player's time.

Comment: Let's not be judging his design - he's asking a technical question. not what you think of his game.  A lot of great games were probably "DUMB" in the eyes of those that didn't get the goal or destination.

Comment: Seems like this is two questions:  (a) how do I tell the player's local time and (b) how do I interpolate between textures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I blend 2 lightmaps for day/night cycle in Unity?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49687/how-do-i-blend-2-lightmaps-for-day-night-cycle-in-unity?rq=1) for a previous question about fading 2 lightmaps for day/night cycles.  It includes an answer that seems to indicate how to do it.  Your challenge will be to get the current time, figure out how much day/night sky you want given that time, and make it so.

In the answer given to the linked question, the shader has a "_Blend" value that you can set between 0.0 and 1.0.  0.0 is fully one skybox, and 1.0 is fully the other.  What you'll want to do is have it be one value during the day, and the other during the night.  Then as the sun goes down, change to the other.  As it rises the next day, change back.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `System.DateTime.Now.Hour` is between the hours you consider to be the night (it is 24h based) and change the skybox texture accordingly and dim all natural lights as well.